# My email server is blacklisted what can I do

Tags: email, smtp, blacklist

I have discovered that my email server has been blacklisted by http://www.five-ten-sg.com

What affect is that going to have on my sending and receiving emails and is there anything I can do about it to fix it.

All the emails I am sending are going out by IIS6 SMTP server, so any suggestions for how to configure this better gratefully received.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried going to http://www.five-ten-sg.com/blackhole.php and asking them why you are blacklisted?

If you are listed as a spammer everybody who uses that blacklist are likely to drop your mail like it was anthrax covered...

Answer (score 0):

Many of the times you can contact your server provider and have them contact these blacklist providers on your behalf. They hosting providers tend to have a little more talking power with these providers.

Also check your http://www.senderbase.org/ reputation every now and then.